# Linear vs Nonlinear method

Tags: linear-algebra, noise

I am doing curve-fitting and I am trying to estimated four parameters. To solve the non-linear least squares curve-ﬁtting problem I used the Levenberg-Marquardt curve-ﬁtting method. To solve the curve-fitting problem in linear least squares sense I used the Singular Value decomposition (I used software to estimated the parameters). When my data are noise free both linear and non-linear least squares method seems to have the same accuracy. When I add noise to my data the linear least-squares method is more sensitive to noise than the non-linear method and I am interested to understand why this happen.

Comment: "The non-linear..."  This usage of the term "non-linear" always bugs me.  There's really only one type of linear function: linear.  But there is an uncountable number of different ways that a function can be non-linear, starting from all the polynomials of degree greater than one.  Which non-linear method are you referring to?

Comment: non-linear least squares method